# Convert const float* to std::array<float, ...>

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

I have a const float* pointing to a huge array, and would like to be able to access the elements through a std::array.
What is the best way to do this? Without copying the elements if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible without undefined behavior. Why do you need it?

Comment: I need to construct an object, and one of the arguments in its constructor is a std::array. And the values are stored in eigen's RealVectorType(https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html#acd090d5fdfc3cc017a13b6d8daa92287)
This type has a data() method, which returns a float*.

Comment: If the class constructor takes an std::array then the size *must* be known at compile time -- right?  Can you show the code for the class you're trying to construct?

Comment: This object you need to construct has a badly designed API if it forces you to use `std::array`.  Can you talk to the developer to improve the API, e. g. accept a pair of iterators instead?

Comment: Yes, I know the size at compile time. This is the class:

http://pastebin.com/FU2vxWBS

I made it, so it is fine to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `std::array`, you need to know the size of the array at compile time. You create an empty array and use `std::copy` to copy the elements into the array.

If the code which uses your `const float*` only knows that size at runtime, then you cannot use `std::array` but have to use `std::vector`. `std::vector` has a constructor to which you can pass pointers to the begin and end of the range to copy into it.

Note that in both cases, the container **owns a copy** of the original elements.

> Without copying the elements if possible.

No, that is not possible. C++ standard containers are designed to own their contents, not just representing a view into them.

Here is an example to illustrate the difference:

```
#define SIZE 10 // let's assume some C or legacy code which uses macros

// ...

void f(const float* arr)
{
    // size is known at compile time
    std::array<float, SIZE> a;
    std::copy(arr, arr + SIZE, begin(a));
}

void g(const float* arr, int size)
{
    // size is only known at runtime
    std::vector<float> v(arr, arr + size);
}
```

Comment: Macros are not a legacy feature.

Comment: @yeoman: Using a macro to define a container size is largely a legacy feature in modern C++. Besides, the comment does not say at all that every use of a macro means legacy code.

Comment: That's true :) But being able to use macros for logging, assertion-like functionality, error handling in exception-free contexts, &c. is actually a strong language feature of C++. Yes, C macros are DUMB. Real macros like LISP and RUST have would be WAY preferrable. But having macros at all, albeit in a form that requires you to really think about how the result is going to be parsed when you write them, helps avoid a lot of boilerplate, which is in most cases a good idea :)

Comment: Yes, I actually know the size.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two proposed additions to the standard library that do something like that.  One is [`std::experimental::to_array<T,N>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/to_array), which makes a deep copy of the entire data.  That’s wasteful in terms of both time and memory, but could be useful if you really do want to create a copy, especially a `const` copy which you cannot create and then modify.

If what you want is a container interface to a range of data represented by an arbitrary pointer and element count, the [Guideline Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) offers a `span` template.  I recommend that, if you pass both, you wrap them in a lightweight object similar to this.

Since you said you can change the interface to the constructor, I strongly suggest you do so.  If you want to keep around the version that takes a `std::array`, you can, and delegate it to the version that takes an arbitrary range of data, such as:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include "span"

MyClass::MyClass( const span<value_type>& s /*, more, params */ )
{ 
 /* In this example, m_storage is some private container and span has a
  * container interface.
  */
  auto it = std::back_inserter(m_storage);
  std::copy_n( s.begin(), s.size(), it );
  // ...
}

MyClass::MyClass( std::array<value_type, initializer_size>& a /*, more, params */ )
: MyClass( span<value_type>( a.data(), a.size() ) /*, more, params */ )
{}
```

Comment: In addition, Microsoft has a class template named `array_view`.

Answer (score 0):

std::array does not take ownership of pointers. You have to copy the elements. Use std::copy. It works on abstract iterators, for which pointers also qualify.

```
const float *source = ...; // C array of at least of size N
std::array<float, N> destination;
std::copy(source, source + N, destination.begin());
```

An aside: without copying the elements, the element type of whatever container with support for taking ownership of a pointer would have to be const float as well. Or you would have to use const_cast<> in case you were sure that the pointer is actually not really to const float. Please, only use const_cast<> in cases where it's absolutely unavoidable due to a flaw in an external API though :)